# Why does the prefix for instance variables remain the same for both the parent and child class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance

I have two classes, Rectangle and Square. Square is the child class to Rectangle.
My issue is when I put in a self.**dict** statement for either class, to check the values for their instances, both have the prefix **_Rectangle** in their keywords. Example, the width for a rectangle instance and square instance would both have the keyword **_Rectangle__width**. I get the prefix is due to me initializing all attributes as private attributes, but why doesn't the prefix change when it is a square instance. I assume for a square instance the width keyword should be **_Square__width**. Is it cause i am initializing the values for my square class using the super() function? Here is my code.

```
class Rectangle(Base):
    def __init__(self, width, height, x=0, y=0, id=None):
        super().__init__(id)
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def to_dictionary(self):
        return self.__dict__

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, size, x=0, y=0, id=None):
        super().__init__(size, size, x, y, id)

    def to_dictionary(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

I tested the function in main using the following code.

```
r2 = Rectangle(5, 5, 5, 5)
rectangle_dict = r2.to_dictionary()
print(rectangle_dict)

s2 = Square(4, 4, 4)
square_dict = s2.to_dictionary()
print(square_dict)
```

The result was

```
{'id': 1, '_Rectangle__width': 5, '_Rectangle__height': 5, '_Rectangle__x': 5, '_Rectangle__y': 5}
{'id': 2, '_Rectangle__width': 4, '_Rectangle__height': 4, '_Rectangle__x': 4, '_Rectangle__y': 4}
```

All the keyword prefixes are the same. Why is that? And I know the to_dictionary method in my Square class is unnecessary as it could easily inherit the same from the Rectangle class, but the results would be the same as above.

Comment: It's based on the class where the method is defined, not the class of the instance. Since `__width` is in `Rectangle.__init__`, it gets the `_Rectangle` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

`Square.__init__` calls `super()` which calls `Rectangle.__init__` and that's where the private variables are assigned. Private variables should only be used by the class that defines them. Inheritors have no business fiddling with them. That's literally *why* they exist. If you want inheritors like `Square` to see these variables, you shouldn't make them private to the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how "private" attributes (so the one that starts with double underscore) works in python. [From docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. (...)

> Name mangling is intended to give classes an easy way to define “private” instance variables and methods, **without having to worry about instance variables defined by derived classes**, or mucking with instance variables by code outside the class. Note that the mangling rules are designed mostly to avoid accidents; it still is possible for a determined soul to access or modify a variable that is considered private.

So you "cannot" override such variable, defining `__width` in `Square` will create both fields, `Rectangle__width` and `Square__width`